# Lightbox effect: image cut in half and drops/slides in

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'd like to have an effect in a lightbox gallery (preferably FancyBox): When clicking on the thumbnail image, the lightbox opens and here it goes:

1. the image needs to get cut in half, with one part dropping or
   sliding in from the top and the other half from the bottom.
2. A little bouncing effect would be great as well, especially for the
   next and previous buttons which need to drop/slide in as well.

Do you know what I mean? Is that possible in Javascript at all? (No Flash if possible.)

I haven't found specific tutorials around the web yet and don't really know which exact term to search for.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do you want a complete solution to this problem, or a guiding hand that will point you in the right direction? SO is not the place for "do this for me" questions.

Comment: Please consider whether it is a worthwhile investment of your time, producing a gimicky effect which will slow down the user. (Personally, I would dislike such an effect.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Yes, I know: I don't want you guys to solve the entire problem for me but I really need something inbetween a tutorial -and- a guiding hand. Sorry *blush*

Comment: P.S.: I guess hints, tricks and links would help at first. Yes.